# Azure Functions Exceptions in Production

Tags: azure-functions

Is there any way to better deal with returned exceptions in a production deployment?

For example, in the below, BadRequestObjectResult ends up showing the exception with a stack trace. While really helpful in development, in production this could allow an attacker to gain insights into the function - which I want to avoid.

I could write my own wrapper - but it seems like this is something that should be controlled better.

I'd also like to deal with unhandled exceptions in the same way (like ASP-.NET does, something like UseDeveloperExceptionPage)

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
namespace AzureFunctionExcpetion
{
    public static class Function1 :
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            try
            {
                throw new Exception("exception thrown");
                return new OkObjectResult("Test Response from function 1");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return new BadRequestObjectResult(ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, if the answer is helpful, could you please accept it as answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Update 0617:**

For your original question, you can use the [C# preprocessor directives](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/).

The code like below:

```
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            try
            {                    
                throw new Exception("exception thrown");
                return new OkObjectResult("Test Response from function 1");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
#if DEBUG
                return new BadRequestObjectResult(ex);
#else                
                return new BadRequestObjectResult("this is a bad request...");
#endif
            }
        }
    }
```

Then when in debug, the developers can see the details error message; when in production, the end users will only see the error like "this is a bad request...".

And for your new issues by using something like `UseDeveloperExceptionPage`, I will give it a try but not sure there is something similar in azure function(and I think it should be a good practice to use `try catch` here.). I will keep you update when any findings.

---

**Original answer:**

Please enable Application insights for azure function as per [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-monitoring?tabs=cmd#view-telemetry-in-application-insights).

Then you can use the LogError method of `ILogger` to write the exception into application insights. The end user cannot see the error details.

Comment: So are you suggesting to always return a 500, and just log info to Insights?  

My pref is to return useful info on debug (making it easier to get that info).

Comment: @Greg, do you mean when in debug, you want to show the details by using `return new BadRequestObjectResult(ex);`; And in production, just return a single error like 500(without showing the details error)?

Comment: Yep.  I'd also like to handle unhandled exceptions in the same way (details in debug, no details in prod - updated original question)